# Node.js: How can I get the reference for a Firebase Database Data Snapshot

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a folder for each user. I have a DataSnapshot name "snapshot" that selects an item of the user that has been changed.
Using the following code, i get the snapshot for the item I want in the same user:

```
var locationSnapshot = snapshot.child("location");
```

This works. My question is how can I get the reference to this exact item in the database so that I can write it? Supposedly there is a function:

```
ref
non-null firebase.database.Reference

The Reference for the location that generated this DataSnapshot.
```

But when I use it, it doesn't work:

```
var locationReference = locationSnapshot.ref();
```

**Question**:
How do I use it or how do I get the reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the latest Firebase SDK, [`ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#ref) is a property and not a function:

```
var locationReference = locationSnapshot.ref;
```

Comment: I just blew an hour on this issue. Thx